# Which EU countries trade more with China than with the US?

Tags: united-states, european-union, china, trade

[News](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-56093378) last year was that China overtook the US as the EU's largest trading partner. ([Apparently](https://www.politico.eu/article/china-not-eu-top-trade-partner-us-is/) that only included good and not services though.) Although COVID-related disruptions probably skewed those statistics somewhat, I'm curious in general which EU countries trade more with China than with the US. (I realize this may be somewhat difficult to account for properly, given how EU imports from China often get accrued to the Netherlands despite their final destinations etc.)

Comment: It must be some, as the levels are so similar.  From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_leading_trade_partners) the whole EU has a total trade with China of $1.09 T and with the USA of $1.11 T so they are very close.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The BBC article you've linked uses figures from [Eurostat](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/portlet_file_entry/2995521/6-15022021-BP-EN.pdf/e8b971dd-7b51-752b-2253-7fdb1786f4d9), but I can't seem to find disaggregated international trade data on their data viewer. Nevertheless, a good substitute is the [UN's COMTRADE database](https://comtrade.un.org/data/), which does provide this information.

Seventeen of the EU27 countries traded more in goods with China than the US in 2021, as shown in the table below (figures in millions of USD). Three countries, Bulgaria, Ireland, and Malta haven't reported figures for 2021 yet, so I've used their 2020 figures.

| Country | China Imp. | China Exp. | US Imp. | US Exp. | China Tot. | US Tot. | China/US (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Slovenia | $6,480 | $400 | $721 | $879 | $6,880 | $1,600 | 430% |
| Czechia | $35,413 | $2,997 | $5,195 | $5,365 | $38,410 | $10,560 | 364% |
| Poland | $49,663 | $3,320 | $10,372 | $8,683 | $52,983 | $19,054 | 278% |
| Romania | $6,379 | $1,341 | $1,035 | $1,851 | $7,720 | $2,887 | 267% |
| Bulgaria <sup>1</sup> | $1,781 | $1,052 | $450 | $644 | $2,834 | $1,094 | 259% |
| Cyprus | $509 | $61 | $139 | $89 | $570 | $229 | 249% |
| Slovakia | $7,438 | $2,665 | $1,106 | $3,308 | $10,104 | $4,414 | 229% |
| Greece | $5,925 | $846 | $1,696 | $1,921 | $6,771 | $3,618 | 187% |
| Malta <sup>1</sup> | $415 | $47 | $119 | $132 | $462 | $250 | 184% |
| Latvia | $1,017 | $189 | $221 | $451 | $1,206 | $671 | 180% |
| Hungary | $9,817 | $2,476 | $2,946 | $4,149 | $12,294 | $7,095 | 173% |
| Finland | $7,765 | $4,228 | $2,735 | $5,401 | $11,993 | $8,137 | 147% |
| Denmark | $9,798 | $4,373 | $4,413 | $5,927 | $14,171 | $10,341 | 137% |
| Spain | $41,200 | $10,243 | $20,213 | $17,469 | $51,444 | $37,682 | 137% |
| Germany | $169,185 | $123,673 | $86,513 | $144,704 | $292,857 | $231,218 | 127% |
| France | $48,194 | $28,339 | $31,089 | $41,246 | $76,532 | $72,335 | 106% |
| Sweden | $12,803 | $7,831 | $5,193 | $15,304 | $20,633 | $20,497 | 101% |
| Netherlands | $63,426 | $16,625 | $47,425 | $33,250 | $80,051 | $80,675 | 99% |
| Croatia | $1,219 | $106 | $681 | $713 | $1,325 | $1,394 | 95% |
| Estonia | $2,106 | $232 | $465 | $1,996 | $2,338 | $2,461 | 95% |
| Austria | $9,337 | $5,757 | $3,874 | $12,352 | $15,094 | $16,226 | 93% |
| Italy | $45,544 | $18,458 | $18,619 | $57,376 | $64,002 | $75,995 | 84% |
| Portugal | $4,600 | $809 | $2,358 | $4,195 | $5,409 | $6,553 | 83% |
| Luxembourg | $760 | $247 | $868 | $425 | $1,007 | $1,293 | 78% |
| Lithuania | $1,855 | $270 | $1,132 | $2,557 | $2,126 | $3,689 | 58% |
| Belgium | $10,786 | $6,163 | $16,474 | $23,751 | $16,950 | $40,225 | 42% |
| Ireland <sup>1</sup> | $7,003 | $11,337 | $14,813 | $56,971 | $18,340 | $71,783 | 26% |
| UK <sup>2</sup> | $91,162 | $20,890 | $59,691 | $59,854 | $112,052 | $119,545 | 94% |
| Norway <sup>2</sup> | $13,119 | $9,330 | $6,273 | $4,441 | $22,448 | $10,714 | 210% |
| Switzerland <sup>2</sup> | $17,669 | $17,435 | $20,890 | $73,148 | $35,104 | $94,037 | 37% |
| TOTAL (EU) | $560,417 | $254,087 | $280,866 | $451,110 | $814,504 | $731,976 | 111% |

Imp. = Import, Exp. = Export, Tot. = Sum of import and export
<sup>1</sup> data from 2020
<sup>2</sup> Non-EU country included for comparison