# Have household savings in Russia increased since 2022?

Tags: russian-federation, economy

We had a bit of a discussion on a recent question whether Russian workers are being "enriched" by the war.

In the US, during WW2 here was rationing etc., which resulted in reduced consumption and [increased savings](https://www.history.com/news/post-world-war-ii-boom-economy).

> by 1945, Americans were saving an average of 21 percent of their personal disposable income, compared to just 3 percent in the 1920s.

After the war ended, much of those savings triggered a boom in consumer goods in the US.

Is the first part of this process happening in Russia now? Have household savings significantly increased in Russia, since the beginning of 2022?

Comment: I found more detailed plot over time of savings in the US, if someone is curious (up to COVID) https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQhYI.png

Comment: Probably better suited for Economics.SE. This site is for questions about "governments, policies and political processes", which don't obviously seem to include questions about household savings.

Comment: "I found more detailed plot over time of savings in the US" Interesting, although around 2000 household saving were quite low and still the US economy was booming.

Comment: @user103496: I think this macro[economics] enough to be on-topic here. (Yes, it may not be an intended effect of any policy, but if we exclude all policy side-effects...)

Comment: @user103496: It's also answerable with gov't statistics rather than any deeper econ theory/modelling etc.

Comment: So are questions like "What is the GDP of Russia?" "How much did Russia export/import in 2023?" "What is the Gini coefficient in Russia?"

Comment: In the USA there were "war bonds" to finance the war effort. Those bonds were heavily advertised as a "patriotic option" (including to soldiers). That removes s lot of money from circulation, helping combat inflation. Think also that the USA was economically booming: its infrastructure intact, its supply lines intact, everything it was producing was bought (either internally or by foreign countries) and a lot of the workforce was "hired" by the government.

Comment: @user103496: I'd say [yes](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/notice-macroeconomics-is-officially-in-scope), but many would be trivial to answer with a google search. We do get here some Qs about who trades with who and how much IIRC. I asked one of those myself in the past https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/73648/which-eu-countries-trade-more-with-china-than-with-the-us In fact, this Q wasn't far from that since CBR had that data, in English.

Comment: A caveat: US had exceptionally stable currency; it's possible that Russian savings will be eaten by either inflation or currency devaluation, even if the course of military actions will be mostly favorable to Russia.

Comment: The scale of WW2 and the conflict in Ukraine does not compare, the way the economy was working in 1945 versus the globalized one we have today have nothing in common. How is it relevant to compare US households savings in 1945 to Russians households savings today ?

Comment: @alamar: somewhat true for that period "Between April 1942 and June 1946, the period of the most stringent federal controls on inflation, the annual rate of inflation was just 3.5 percent; the annual rate had been 10.3 percent in the six months before April 1942 and it soared to 28.0 percent in the six months after June 1946".

Comment: You can't compare post WW2 US to Russia's now and near future.  In the case of the US in 1940 there was massive under-utilization of existing industrial assets due to the Great Depression.  Whereas Russia is starting this with a creaky economy and weak industrial base.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs in skeptics or economics but not politics

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the CBR [has](https://www.cbr.ru/eng/statistics/macro_itm/households/hh/) this data in English. There was spike in household savings in 2022, right after the start of the war, and it's been higher than before the war since then, except for Q2 2022, in roubles at least. (IDK what accounts for that contrary movement that quarter.) One might guess the shock of sanctions and CBR counter-measures (rate increase, currency exchange limitations) accounted for some of those. As for the savings in foreign currencies, those had spike as the war started (probably due to inability with exchange), but after that there were sustained small negative values, which I guess are people exchanging their "bottled" personal foreign reserves for one reason or another.

[image]

So, yeah, Russian households are "enriched" with rouble savings by this war, apparently, at least in the form of cash, which I think it's only what that graph shows because there's another one on that page on "Households investment in deposits (transactions, bln rubles)", which is a somewhat odd (for me) way of saying savings kept in bank accounts. These have much more variation (and the breakdown by various institution types also complicates this picture) but the overall blue line is positive after Q2 2022:

[image]

It looks like there was a little "bank run" as the war started. So the household savings in cash in Q1 2022 may actually be well explained by withdrawals from banks. And maybe the Q2 2022 cash savings reduction is a reflection of a reversal of that process, i.e. people put money back in banks after the initial scare. OTOH, after that (i.e. Q3 2022 and later) it seems we have an increase in both cash savings and bank deposits, almost "in sync" in terms of magnitudes, each quarter.

There are more graphs for "debt securities" (bonds I guess) and [mutual?] "fund shares", but I'm not sure how many Russians use those instruments. Anyhow, those graphs are somewhat similar, but they seem to show less increase compared to pre-war, relative to the above two [graphs].

TLDR: it does look like Russian households are accumulating a bit of savings as a result of the economic conditions during this war.